# How to add .git directory in visual studio 2017 project

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I use the visual studio team services (VSTS) to keep track of my projects and to back them up.

I have also GitHub repo of the project because it is needed for the distribution of the project.

My computer crashed and I have to add the repository to GitHub again. I found away around but it would be easier if the .git filedirectory could be added to the project and also be backed up to the VSTS.

Comment: This question is not very understandable. Could you rephrase it? You cloned the repo again from TFS and want to add the remote toward GitHub? You want to switch between the 'origin' remote and the GitHub/backup one? What 'map' means in term of git? What do you mean with TFS? Do you talk about TFVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the .git map not hidden in windows file explorer and add it it to the project

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting.  What do you mean by "add it to the project"?

Comment: i thought a project is a very basic concept in visual studio , when you make an app you start a project , a vb project a javascript project or a node project or a c# or C++ project, when files are copied from other locations to your project ditrectory you have to add them to your project otherwise they wont be saved and back uppedon the tfs when checking in